# Weird internet connection problem

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, internet

My friend just had an internet connection problem. Her handphone (Acer Liquid C1, Android OS maybe 4.0) have a problem in the connection. It could connect to Line application and chat normally, then it could read and reply some mail in Gmail. Also she can refresh feed on Instagram.

But, it's BBM (blackberry messenger) couldn't chat normally (in this case, my BBM message just sent to her's [appeared as a tick], but not delivered [not appeared in **D**] to her BBM).

The other problem in this case is:

- when the handphone connect to a mobile hotspot from apple / blackberry device and wireless router from apple, sometimes the device (my friend's handphone) is disconnect from the wifi after exit the setting menu. But when she open the wifi setting menu, the handphone is connected.
- But, when her handphone connect to a mobile hotspot from android device (in this case, the mobile hotspot is asus tab and samsung smartphone), the device is always connected.

Another clue in this case is, when her android access play store and trying to download an app like Twitter with mobile data or hotspot from apple device, it always give an error code like 4xx or 9xx (I forgot this, but the first number is correct). But when it connect to wifi (from android mobile hotspot), it can download the application.

If someone can solve this, my friend will be glad :D

Sorry for my bad English :(